# How do I populate my textboxes?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, textbox

I am making a website for my internship and I came across a problem. Retrieving data from my database into my textboxes. If possible, each person their own information. For example; I have a textbox for John, he has a name and email. Jack also has a name and email. Both need to be selected from the database and put in the form. It's a form where you can make changes to the persons information. You can see the website yourself [here](http://imthesolution.esy.es/). Click on the button "Wijzig" to view the form I mean.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<tr>
  <td width="100">
    <div id="flip">
      <img src="images/ik.jpg" class="circular" width="100px" height="100px">
      <td width="350px">
        <label for="luca" style="width: 280px;">Luca Fraser</label>

        <div id="panel" style="display: none;">Geboortedatum: 30-12-1997
          <br>Email: lucaf1997@gmail.com
          <br>Woonplaats: Winterswijk
        </div>
      </td>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="luca">Voorzitter</label>
  </td>
  <td style="border-color: transparent;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm" style="background-color: #42a5f5; border-color: #42a5f5; margin-left: 20px;">Wijzig
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                            Wijzigen
                                        </h4>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal Body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Voornaam</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="Here needs to get a input value, look at line 247 to see where it needs to be." />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Achternaam</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Janssen" />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="jan@janssen.nl" />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Telefoonnummer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="0612345678" />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Functie</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Voorzitter" />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal Footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              Save changes
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </td>
  <td style="border-color: transparent;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction()">Verwijder</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You would need to pass the values collected from the database to Javascript and than fill it with Javascript.

Comment: Try to send a ajax request to database and fill the form according to the user or if number are records show to be small then load the values on page load

Comment: You can use ajax for that see this  -http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: Hey Luca: Sorry to have teased you in the other question, but the first thing you need to know about development ESPECIALLY in Holland. _Niemand mag zomaar persoonsgegevens van een ander op internet publiceren._

Comment: It's fine. Though, how do you know that? Try living here and you'll find out that nobody cares about that. Seriously.. But how do you know those Dutch rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write jquery code to get values from labels or DOM elements and display on respective input boxes.

> value = $("#labelid").val();

But you need to make your HTML standardize like use unique id's for labels.